# Помогите исправить тест на Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, тестирование

При запуске Java приложения с двумя кнопками, стартует и браузер. А потом мне нужно, чтобы при нажатие на дну кнопку запускался один тест, при нажатие на вторую, другой тест. Нот так, как я написал, оно не работает.

```
package firstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class FirstScript extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public FirstScript() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Start");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(0, 102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(0, 454, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    driver.get("https://vk.com/im");
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     driver.get("https://www.google.com.ua/");
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=e:\\Duh\\Portable\\Browser\\centbrowser32\\User Data\\");
    options.setBinary("E:\\Duh\\Portable\\Browser\\centbrowser32\\chrome.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Duh\\Portable\\Browser\\centbrowser32\\chromedriver.exe");    
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
              
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FirstScript().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не видно где вы инициализируете вэбдрайвер. Если это переменная класса, то ее надо инициализировать как-то так

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

а у вас локальная переменная

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```